# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException :Erreur lors de la configuration de la classe d'écoute de l'application

Tags: java, maven, jar

In my web project (Maven) , I'm using a custom jar, it's declared in the `web.xml`,
the project is builded successfully, but when I tried to start `tomcat` I had this error

```
Erreur lors de la configuration de la classe d'écoute de l'application (application listener) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

I tried to solve the problem with several method such as `web deployment assembly`, I clean the project, tomcat and I updated the project but still the same problem.
What can I do to resolve this problem ??

Comment: I would search for solutions to the English version of this error.

Answer (score 0):

The reason ClassNotFoundException is thrown could be multiple. If you are sure that the class for which this exception is being thrown; is present in the third party jar, then you can either, place the jar in WEB-INF/lib directory of the application (make sure your build scripts are doing this), or you can put this jar in the classpath of your tomcat.